# How to extract specific values from a list in JSON response with PHP?

Tags: php, json, parsing

I am executing an API request, which gives a JSON response like this -

[image]

This JSON is too complex for me to work with, so I was looking for a way to eliminate useless stuff. The final JSON I would like should look somewhat like this -

[image]

---

Which means, I am eliminating all items except `Display` in the `records` list, and adding them all in a separate list, which just contains the display values. Is it possible to modify JSON with PHP?

Your help/advice will be very appreciated!

Comment: You don't modify "the JSON", you modify the _data structure_ you get after _decoding_ the JSON. And then you _encode_ the result as JSON again, when you are done with your structural modifications.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need to do - decode your json to an array, loop through it and create a new array from it and then convert the new array back to json!
-- I created a mock json that is close to yours for this example:

```
<?php

$json = '{"record":[
    {
        "id": "FirstId1",
        "fields": {
            "Display": "ADANI NAVINASH"
        },
        "created_time" : "20939290"
    },
    {
        "id": "2ndId2",
        "fields": {
            "Display": "AGRWAL DDDDW"
        },
        "created_time" : "2343223455"
    }
],
"offset": "dsfdgfdsg23432fd"
}';

$array = json_decode($json,true);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);

$newArray = []; //Set our new array;
foreach($array['record'] as $record){ //We loop to create our new array
    $newArray['records'][] = $record['fields']['Display']; //add the Displays each to a different key
}
$newArray['offset'] = $array['offset']; // add the offset (only one and outside of record so out of the loop)
$newJson = json_encode($newArray); //At the end of it all we take our new array and turn it back to json!
print_r("The new Json: " . $newJson); // print our new json
```

Which will return this:

```
Array
(
    [record] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => FirstId1
                    [fields] => Array
                        (
                            [Display] => ADANI NAVINASH
                        )

                    [created_time] => 20939290
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2ndId2
                    [fields] => Array
                        (
                            [Display] => AGRWAL DDDDW
                        )

                    [created_time] => 2343223455
                )

        )

    [offset] => dsfdgfdsg23432fd
)
The new Json: {"records":["ADANI NAVINASH","AGRWAL DDDDW"],"offset":"dsfdgfdsg23432fd"}
```